# Replicate React Context in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-context

I'd like to replicate the behavior of React Context in Nodejs but I'm struggling with it.

In React, by creating only one context, I can provide and consume different values in my components, depending on the `value` given to the `<Provider/>`. So the following works:

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext(0);

const MyConsumer = () => { 
  return (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {value => {
        return <div>{value}</div>
      }}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  )
}

const App = () => 
    <React.Fragment>
      <MyContext.Provider value={1}>
        <MyConsumer/>
      </MyContext.Provider>
      <MyContext.Provider value={2}>
        <MyConsumer/>
      </MyContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

However I have no idea how to implement this in Nodejs. I've taken a look at the source code of React Context but it does not help much... Here is what I got so far:

```js
// context.js
export const createContext = (defaultValue: number) => {
  const context = {
    value: defaultValue,
    withContext: null,
    useContext: null,
  };
  function withContext(value: number, callback: (...args: any[]) => any) {
    context.value = value;
    return callback;
  }
  function useContext() {
    return context;
  }

  context.withContext = withContext;
  context.useContext = useContext;

  return context;
};

// functions.js
import { context } from "./index";
export function a() {
  const result = context.useContext();

  console.log(result);
}

export function b() {
  const result = context.useContext();

  console.log(result);
}

// index.js
import { createContext } from "./context";
import { a, b } from "./functions";

export const context = createContext(0);

const foo = context.withContext(1, a);
const bar = context.withContext(2, b);

console.log("foo", foo());
console.log("bar", bar());
```

Obviously, `value` is overwritten and `2` is logged twice.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What will be the use case? Can you give a real use? The sample use case doesn't make much sense to help understand the problem you are trying to solve in nodejs.

Comment: My use case: I'm running two express servers locally, each one connected to its own DB. I'm using `typeorm` and I need to keep both connections names as "default" but it does not work since the two servers seem to share the same instance of `typeorm`. My thought is that having something like React Context in Nodejs could enclose each server with its own instance of `typeorm`. Apart from that, I think this pattern could apply to any case where we need a "context" in nodejs.

Answer (score 11):

### 2022 update

NodeJS is proposing a new built-in for doing exactly that: [Asynchronous context tracking](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#asynchronous-context-tracking).

Thanks to @Emmanuel Meric de Bellefon for pointing this out.

---

## Defining the desired behavior

If you only need it for *synchronous* code, you could do something relatively simple. All you need is to specify where the boundaries are.

In React, you do this with JSX

```
<Context.Provider value={2}>
  <MyComponent />
</Context.Provider>
```

In this example, the value of `Context` will be `2` for `MyComponent` but outside of the bounds of `<Context.Provider>` it will be whatever the value was before that.

If I were to translate that in vanilla JS, I would probably want it to look something like this:

```js
const myFunctionWithContext = context.provider(2, myFunction)
myFunctionWithContext('an argument')
```

In this example, I would expect the value of `context` to be `2` within `myFunction` but outside of the bounds of `context.provider()` it would be whatever value was set before.

## How to work the problem

At its most basic, this could be solved by a global object

```js
// we define a "context"
globalThis.context = 'initial value'

function a() {
  // we can access the context
  const currentValue = globalThis.context
  console.log(`context value in a: ${currentValue}`)

  // we can modify the context for the "children"
  globalThis.context = 'value from a'
  b()

  // we undo the modification to restore the context
  globalThis.context = currentValue
}

function b() {
  console.log(`context value in b: ${globalThis.context}`)
}

a()
```

Now we know that it's never wise to pollute the global scope `globalThis` or `window`. So we could use a [Symbol](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) instead, to make sure there can't be any naming conflict:

```js
const context = Symbol()

globalThis[context] = 'initial value'

function a() {
  console.log(`context value in a: ${globalThis[context]}`)
}

a()
```

However, even though this solution will never cause a conflict with the global scope, it's still not ideal, and doesn't scale well for multiple contexts. So let's make a "context factory" module:

```js
// in createContext.js
const contextMap = new Map() // all of the declared contexts, one per `createContext` call

/* export default */ function createContext(value) {
    const key = Symbol('context') // even though we name them the same, Symbols can never conflict
    contextMap.set(key, value)

    function provider(value, callback) {
        const old = contextMap.get(key)
        contextMap.set(key, value)
        callback()
        contextMap.set(key, old)
    }

    function consumer() {
        return contextMap.get(key)
    }

    return {
        provider,
        consumer,
    }
}

// in index.js
const contextOne = createContext('initial value')
const contextTwo = createContext('other context') // we can create multiple contexts without conflicts

function a() {
    console.log(`value in a: ${contextOne.consumer()}`)
    contextOne.provider('value from a', b)
    console.log(`value in a: ${contextOne.consumer()}`)
}

function b() {
    console.log(`value in b: ${contextOne.consumer()}`)
    console.log(`value in b: ${contextTwo.consumer()}`)
}

a()
```

Now, as long as you're only using this for synchronous code, this works by simply overriding a value before a callback and reseting it after (in `provider`).

## Solution for synchronous code

If you want to structure your code like you would in react, here's what it would look like with a few separate modules:

```js
// in createContext.js
const contextMap = new Map()

/* export default */ function createContext(value) {
    const key = Symbol('context')
    contextMap.set(key, value)
    return {
        provider(value, callback) {
            const old = contextMap.get(key)
            contextMap.set(key, value)
            callback()
            contextMap.set(key, old)
        },
        consumer() {
            return contextMap.get(key)
        }
    }
}

// in myContext.js
/* import createContext from './createContext.js' */
const myContext = createContext('initial value')
/* export */ const provider = myContext.provider
/* export */ const consumer = myContext.consumer

// in a.js
/* import { provider, consumer } from './myContext.js' */
/* import b from './b.js' */
/* export default */ function a() {
    console.log(`value in a: ${consumer()}`)
    provider('value from a', b)
    console.log(`value in a: ${consumer()}`)
}

// in b.js
/* import { consumer } from './myContext.js' */
/* export default */ function b() {
    console.log(`value in b: ${consumer()}`)
}

// in index.js
/* import a from './a.js' */
a()
```

## Going further: the problem of asynchronous code

The solution proposed above would not work if `b()` was an async function, because as soon as `b` returns, the context value is reset to its value in `a()` (that's how `provider` works). For example:

```js
const contextMap = new Map()
function createContext(value) {
    const key = Symbol('context')
    contextMap.set(key, value)

    function provider(value, callback) {
        const old = contextMap.get(key)
        contextMap.set(key, value)
        callback()
        contextMap.set(key, old)
    }
    
    function consumer() {
        return contextMap.get(key)
    }

    return {
        provider,
        consumer
    }
}

const { provider, consumer } = createContext('initial value')
function a() {
    console.log(`value in a: ${consumer()}`)
    provider('value from a', b)
    console.log(`value in a: ${consumer()}`)
}

async function b() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
  console.log(`value in b: ${consumer()}`) // we want this to log 'value from a', but it logs 'initial value'
}

a()
```

So far, I don't really see how to manage the issue of async functions properly, but I bet it could be done with the use of `Symbol`, `this` and `Proxy`.

## Using `this` to pass `context`

While developing a solution for synchronous code, we've seen that we can "afford" to add properties to an object that "isn't ours" as long as we're using `Symbol` keys to do so (like we did on `globalThis` in the first example). We also know that functions are always called with an implicit `this` argument that is either

- the global scope (`globalThis`),
- the parent scope (when calling `obj.func()`, within `func`, `this` will be `obj`)
- an arbitrary scope object (when using `.bind`, `.call` or `.apply`)
- in some cases, an arbitrary primitive value (only possible in strict mode)

In addition, javascript lets us define a [Proxy](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to be the interface between an object and whatever script uses that object. Within a `Proxy` we can define a set of [traps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions) that will each handle a specific way in which our object is used. The one that is interesting for our issue is [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) which traps *function calls* and gives us access to the `this` that the function will be called with.

Knowing this, we can "augment" the `this` of our function called with a context provider `context.provider(value, myFunction)` with a Symbol referring to our context:

```js
{
    apply: (target, thisArg = {}, argumentsList) => {
        const scope = Object.assign({}, thisArg, {[id]: key}) // augment `this`
        return Reflect.apply(target, scope, argumentsList) // call function
    }
}
```

*`Reflect` will call the function `target` with `this` set to `scope` and the arguments from `argumentsList`*

As long as what we "store" in `this` allows us to get the "current" value of the scope (the value where `context.provider()` was called) then we should be able to access this value from within `myFunction` and we don't need to set/reset a unique object like we did for the synchronous solution.

## First async solution: shallow context

Putting it all together, here's an initial attempt at a asynchronous solution for a react-like context. However, unlike with the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), `this` is not inherited automatically when a function is called from within another function. Because of this the context in the following solution only survives 1 level of function calls:

```js
function createContext(initial) {
    const id = Symbol()

    function provider(value, callback) {
        return new Proxy(callback, {
            apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
                const scope = Object.assign({}, thisArg, {[id]: value})
                return Reflect.apply(target, scope, argumentsList)
            }
        })
    }
    
    function consumer(scope = {}) {
        return id in scope ? scope[id] : initial
    }

    return {
        provider,
        consumer,
    }
}

const myContext = createContext('initial value')

function a() {
    console.log(`value in a: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
    const bWithContext = myContext.provider('value from a', b)
    bWithContext()
    const cWithContext = myContext.provider('value from a', c)
    cWithContext()
    console.log(`value in a: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
}

function b() {
    console.log(`value in b: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
}

async function c() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))
    console.log(`value in c: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`) // works in async!
    b() // logs 'initial value', should log 'value from a' (the same as "value in c")
}

a()
```

## Second asynchronous solution: context forwarding

A potential solution for the context to survive a function call within another function call could be to have to *explicitly* forward the context to any function call (which could quickly become cumbersome). From the example above, `c()` would change to:

```js
async function c() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))
    console.log(`value in c: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
    const bWithContext = myContext.forward(this, b)
    bWithContext() // logs 'value from a'
}
```

where `myContext.forward` is just a `consumer` to get the value and directly afterwards a `provider` to pass it along:

```js
function forward(scope, callback) {
    const value = consumer(scope)
    return provider(value, callback)
}
```

Adding this to our previous solution:

```js
function createContext(initial) {
    const id = Symbol()

    function provider(value, callback) {
        return new Proxy(callback, {
            apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
                const scope = Object.assign({}, thisArg, {[id]: value})
                return Reflect.apply(target, scope, argumentsList)
            }
        })
    }
    
    function consumer(scope = {}) {
        return id in scope ? scope[id] : initial
    }

    function forward(scope, callback) {
        const value = consumer(scope)
        return provider(value, callback)
    }

    return {
        provider,
        consumer,
        forward,
    }
}

const myContext = createContext('initial value')

function a() {
    console.log(`value in a: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
    const bWithContext = myContext.provider('value from a', b)
    bWithContext()
    const cWithContext = myContext.provider('value from a', c)
    cWithContext()
    console.log(`value in a: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
}

function b() {
    console.log(`value in b: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
}

async function c() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))
    console.log(`value in c: ${myContext.consumer(this)}`)
    const bWithContext = myContext.forward(this, b)
    bWithContext()
}

a()
```

## Context on async functions without explicit forwarding

Now I'm stuck... I'm open to ideas!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Sheraff! Although your solution is really good for synchronous functions, I do need something for asynchronous code, which the other answer provides. Thanks again!

Comment: This a really, really nice answer.

Comment: Now there is the builtin [async context tracking](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#asynchronous-context-tracking) from nodejs.

Answer (score 5):

Your goal of "replicating React's Context in NodeJS" is *slightly* ambiguous. From the React docs:

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

There are no component trees in NodeJS. The closest analogy that I could think of (based also on your example) was a call stack. Additionally, React's Context also causes a re-render of the tree if the value changes. I have no idea what that would mean in NodeJS, so I'll happily ignore this aspect.

Thus I will assume that you are essentially looking for a way to **make a value accessible anywhere in the call stack without having to pass it down the stack as an argument** from function to function.

I propose you use one of the so-called **continuation-local storage** libs for NodeJS to achieve this. They use a pattern that is a little different from what you were trying to do, but it might be just fine.

My favourite has been [CLS Hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked) (no affiliation). It taps into NodeJS's async_hooks system to preserve the provided context even if there are asynchronous calls in the stack. Last published 4 years ago it still works as expected.

I rewrote your example using CLS Hooked, although I'd argue that it's not the nicest / most intuitive way to use it. I also added an extra function call to demonstrate that it's possible to override values (i.e. create sort of child contexts). Finally, there's one noticeable difference - the context must now have an ID. If you wish to stick with this React Contexty pattern, you'll probably have to make peace with it.

```js
// context.js

import cls from "cls-hooked";

export const createContext = (contextID, defaultValue) => {
  const ns = cls.createNamespace(contextID);

  return {
    provide(value, callback) {
      return () =>
        ns.run(() => {
          ns.set("value", value);
          callback();
        });
    },
    useContext() {
      return ns.active ? ns.get("value") : defaultValue;
    }
  };
};
```

```js
// my-context.js

// your example had a circular dependency problem
// the context has to be created in a separate file

import { createContext } from "./context";

export const context = createContext("my-context", 0);
```

```js
// zz.js

import { context } from "./my-context";

export const zz = function () {
  console.log("zz", context.useContext());
};
```

```js
// functions.js

import { context } from "./my-context";
import { zz } from "./zz";

export const a = function () {
  const zzz = context.provide("AAA", zz);

  zzz();

  const result = context.useContext();

  console.log("a", result);
};

export const b = function () {
  const zzz = context.provide("BBB", zz);

  zzz();

  const result = context.useContext();

  console.log("b", result);
};
```

```js
// index.js

import { context } from "./c";
import { a, b } from "./functions";

const foo = context.provide(1, a);
const bar = context.provide(2, b);

console.log("default value", context.useContext());
foo();
bar();
```

Running `node index` logs:

```
default value 0
zz AAA
a 1
zz BBB
b 2
```

This would also work if there were all sorts of asynchronous calls happening in your stack.

## How I use it

My approach is a little different. I wasn't trying to replicate React's Context, which also has a limitation in that it is always bound to a single value.

```js
// cls.ts

import cls from "cls-hooked";

export class CLS {
  constructor(private readonly NS_ID: string) {}

  run<T>(op: () => T): T {
    return (cls.getNamespace(this.NS_ID) || cls.createNamespace(this.NS_ID)).runAndReturn(op);
  }

  set<T>(key: string, value: T): T {
    const ns = cls.getNamespace(this.NS_ID);
    if (ns && ns.active) {
      return ns.set(key, value);
    }
  }

  get(key: string): any {
    const ns = cls.getNamespace(this.NS_ID);
    if (ns && ns.active) {
      return ns.get(key);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// operations-cls.ts

import { CLS } from "./cls";

export const operationsCLS = new CLS("operations");
```

```js
// consumer.ts

import { operationsCLS } from "./operations-cls";

export const consumer = () => {
  console.log(operationsCLS.get("some-value")); // logs 123
};
```

```js
// app.ts

import { operationsCLS } from "./operations-cls";
import { consumer } from "./consumer";

cls.run(async () => {
  cls.set("some-value", 123);
  consumer();
});
```

## How CLS works

I prefer to view CLS as magic, as it's always worked fine without my intervention, so can't comment much here, sorry :]

Comment: That seems like a pretty good solution. I just have one question: if you call `zz()` from within `a()` without first wrapping it in `context.provide`. Which value does it log, `0` or `1`?

Comment: It logs 1 : ] 1 was provided initially and this value propagates down the stack, unless it is changed somewhere down the line, which is what my example is attempting to display.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Actually I couldn't achieve what I wanted (creating two default connections in the same process), but your answer is elegant. I think it could be used for other purposes.